# POST request works on Postman but gets 403 when requested by Retrofit

Tags: http, kotlin, retrofit, postman, http-status-code-403

I am trying to login to server using POST request.

The problem is, that when I request it using Postman, everything works, but when requested using retrofit, I get 403 forbidden.

Here is my request using postman[image: postman] As expected, I replaced my name and password with dummy strings as this is a private server. And here is my retrofit code:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("system/login.pl")
fun login(@Header("cache-control") cacheControl: String = "no-cache",
          @Field("login_hidden", encoded = true) loginHidden: String = "1",
          @Field("destination", encoded = true) destination: String = "/auth",
          @Field("credential_0", encoded = true) username: String = "",
          @Field("credential_1", encoded = true) password: String = ""
): Flowable<Response<String>>
```

Also here is my definition for OKHTTP client if someone needed that:

```
private fun makeOkHttpClient(httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .addNetworkInterceptor { chain ->
                chain.proceed(
                        chain.request()
                                .newBuilder()
                                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0")
                                .build()
                )
            }
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
}
```

Comment: Try logging the full request you're sending via Retrofit from a new network interceptor and compare it with what you get from Postman by clicking on the "code" button in the top right corner. If there's any difference that may explain why you're getting a different response

Comment: I've already tried that. Also tried to import code from postman to app and it did not work at all.

Comment: Then it could be related to redirects: by default Postman is configured to follow redirects and to store cookies, while OkHttp follows redirect but doesn't store/send any cookies unless you configure it to do so. Did you check if Postman has any cookies saved?

Comment: I did it to primarily get a specific cookie. But I came around this issue with my specific solution with webView and Javascript